# show lines in each edge of the rectangle

Tags: html, svg

I wanted to create a graphics where there will be a rectangle node in the center and from each of it's corner edges, draw a cross line. That means 4 lines in 4 corner edge of the rectangle.

I could only show some lines in the top left edge of the rectangle. Can anyone guide me on how to show other three lines from that rectangle, please? I did not understand the line concept from the docs

Here is the demo

```html
<svg width="800" height="600" viewbox="0 0 800 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 100)">
      <rect width="200" height="60" rx="5" ry="5">
      </rect>
      <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
        Root Node
      </text>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="90" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" transform="rotate(-220)"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="90" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" transform="rotate(-220)"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="90" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" transform="rotate(-220)"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="90" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" transform="rotate(-220)"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

http://jsbin.com/jucosalice/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw cross lines at each corner without calculating coordinates, you can use `rotate` and `translate` properties:

```html
<svg width="800" height="600" viewbox="0 0 800 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 100)">
      
      <rect width="200" height="60" rx="5" ry="5">
      </rect>
      
      <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
        Root Node
      </text>
                
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="rotate(-135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(200 0) rotate(-45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(0 60) rotate(135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(200 60) rotate(45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>

    </g>
  </svg>
```

Explanation:

The X axis is from left to right, the Y axis is from top to bottom. The direction of rotation is clockwise. So, the code

```
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(200 0) rotate(-45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
```

draws a line from (0,0) to (100,0), translate(shift) it by 200 unit in X direction towards right (as it is width of main rectangle), and then rotate it by -45 deg to get its slope.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) for their documentation.

Comment: I just could not understand that x1,y1,x2,y2 part. Is this the axis used for ithttps://www.google.com.np/search?q=xy+axis&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQiM_ihcjZAhUT4o8KHYdfCoMQ_AUICigB&biw=1435&bih=697#imgrc=ItEcJPrS5q8jiM:

Comment: @Serenity no its not as in your search url image! as i mentioned in answer, the X axis is from left to right, the Y axis is from TOP to BOTTOM.

Comment: how is the calculation done for those 4 lines with rect in those 4 lines ? I could not figure out how to show it dynamically by keeping them in loop. Can you share your idea, please?

Comment: @Serenity With `<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 100)"` we have said the whole graphics shall be shifted by dx=250, dy=100 (this will cause to shift rect from 0,0 at left-top corner to center of panel). The main rect is drawn at x=0, y=0, width=200, height=60. The 4 cross lines are drawn as: consider a horizontal line from 0,0 with a width of 100 unit. then translate(shift) it to each corner and rotate it properly +/- (45 or 90+45). I hope this help

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="800" height="600" viewbox="0 0 800 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 100)">
      <rect width="200" height="60" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
      <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
        Root Node
      </text>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="-75" y2="-75" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
      <line x1="200" y1="60" x2="275" y2="135" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
      <line x1="200" y1="0" x2="275" y2="-75" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="60" x2="-75" y2="135" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good but it may be better to use some `rotate/translate` to find those x,y coordinate numbers...